# Error getting details of PayPal v2 Order created on client side

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a website with a membership with 3 pages, one for presenting the membership (with my PayPal button), one with registration form (for adding the member in my database) and a last one when all this is complete( say " you can now login ").

I just followed a video on YouTube to add the PayPal button for my member to pay an amount before starting filling the registration form.

I am using PayPal SDK. Here is my code:

**FIRST PAGE (account-step1.php)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <?php
  // Include HEADER  
  include ("includes/head.php");
  ?>
    <!-- SPECIFIC CSS -->
    <link href="css/booking-sign_up.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
    .circle {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      line-height: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
      background: gold;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    /* Media query for mobile viewport */
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        #paypal-button-container {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
        
    /* Media query for desktop viewport */
    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
        #paypal-button-container {
            width: 250px;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>
</head>

<body>
                
    <header class="header_in clearfix">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.php">
                <img src="img/logo_sticky.svg" width="250" height="40" alt="" class="logo_sticky">
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php include ("includes/topmenu.php"); ?>
        <a href="#0" class="open_close">
            <i class="icon_menu"></i><span>Menu</span>
        </a>
        <?php include ("includes/menu.php"); ?>
    </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->
    
    <main class="bg_gray pattern">
        
        <div class="container margin_60_40">        
            <div class="main_title center">
                <span><em></em></span>
                <h2><?php echo _e("Our Subscription Plan"); ?></h2>
                <p>VIP 2021 - 2022</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="sign_up">
                        <div class="head">
                            <div class="title">
                            <h3>1 YEAR SUBSCRIPTION</h3>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /head -->
                        <div class="main text-center" style="font-size:16px;">
                                <p><i class="icon_star"></i> <?php echo _e("VIP Membership Card"); ?> <i class="icon_star"></i></p>
                                <p><i class="icon_star"></i> <?php echo _e("Take advantage of original discounts at all our partners everywhere near you"); ?> <i class="icon_star"></i></p>
                                <p><i class="icon_star"></i> <?php echo _e("Your subscription pays for itself in just 1 or 2 uses of discounts"); ?> <i class="icon_star"></i></p>
                                <p><i class="icon_star"></i> <?php echo _e("Each year your easy-to-use privileges are recharged in the application to make you enjoy again"); ?> <i class="icon_star"></i></p>
                                <p><i class="icon_star"></i> <?php echo _e("Contribute to better nutritional health for our children with $ 1 donated to the Club des petits déjeuners by subscription"); ?> <i class="icon_star"></i></p>
                                <p class="text-center">
                                <center>
                                <div class="circle">20$</div>
                                </center>
                                </p>
                                <hr>
                                <center><div id="paypal-button-container"></div></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /box_booking -->
                </div>
                <!-- /col -->

            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
        
    </main>
    <!-- /main -->

    <?php include ("includes/footer.php"); ?>

    <div id="toTop"></div><!-- Back to top button -->
    
    <div class="layer"></div><!-- Opacity Mask Menu Mobile -->
    
    <?php include("includes/signin-modal.php"); ?>
    
    <!-- COMMON SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/common_scripts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common_func.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/validate.js"></script>
    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AeQdfTQ2soaOdV7vgLYyTsnsSC3ptpSJJWFsDGwkTXmQocaCBfYPYWV7mHO-iPGX3_ZiLdCqxmqY9h6H&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
    color:   'gold',
    shape:   'pill',
    label:   'pay'
  },
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '20.00'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function() {
        window.location = "transaction-completed.php?&orderID="+data.orderID;

      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**transaction-completed.php**

```html
<?php

namespace Sample;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
require 'paypal-client.php';
$orderID = $_GET['orderID'];

class GetOrder
{

  // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
   */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
  {

    // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));

    // Transaction Details
    $orderID = $response->result->id;
    $email = $response->result->payer->email_address;
    $pre_name = $response->result->payer->given_name;
    $last_name = $response->result->payer->surname;
    $full_name = $pre_name.$last_name;

    // INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE
    include('db_paypal.php'); //CONNECT DATABASE
    // PREPARE AND BIND
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payments (fullname, orderID) VALUES (?, ?) ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $orderID);
    $stmt->execute();

    //TRY TO EXECUTE QUERY
    if (!$stmt) {
      echo 'Error SQL' .mysqli_error($con);
    }
    else{
      session_start(); //START SESSION
      $_SESSION['orderID'] = $orderID; //STORE orderID INTO SESSION VAR
      header("Location:account-step3.php"); //REDIRECT TO NEXT STEP
    }

    $stmt->close(); //CLOSE STATEMENT
    $con->close(); //CLOSE CONNECTION SQL

  }
}

/**
 *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
 *sample order details.
 *
 *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create an order
 *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
 */
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  GetOrder::getOrder($orderID, true);
}
?>
```

**paypal-client.php**

```html
<?php

namespace Sample;

use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
// GO LIVE \LiveEnvironment
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');

class PayPalClient
{
    /**
     * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
     * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
     * credentials have access.
     */
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }

    /**
     * Set up and return PayPal PHP SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
     * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use \LiveEnvironment.
     */
    public static function environment()
    {
        $clientId = getenv("CLIENT_ID") ?: "AeQdfTQ2soaOdV7vgLYyTsnsSC3ptpSJJWFsDGwkTXmQocaCBfYPYWV7mHO-iPGX3_ZiLdCqxmqY9h6H";
        $clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ?: "ECMtmwnFIMs09g_UFAGBAabjkOgykKORvIC9Y9xW2Mn2aZRx0bH7DpHyXDFg3klRkzV9nUI8T6HRI1e8";
        return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }
}
```

**db_paypal.php**

```html
<?php 

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "password";
$db = "superrabais";

$con = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed:" . $con->connect_error);
}

 ?>
```

and Last one where finally the register form is: **account-step2.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <?php
  // Include HEADER  
  include ("includes/head.php");
  ?>
<?php if (empty($_SESSION['orderID'])) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.replace('../index.php');</script>";
}else{}
?>
    <!-- SPECIFIC CSS -->
    <link href="css/booking-sign_up.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
                
    <header class="header_in clearfix">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.php">
                <img src="img/logo_sticky.svg" width="250" height="40" alt="" class="logo_sticky">
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php include ("includes/topmenu.php"); ?>
        <a href="#0" class="open_close">
            <i class="icon_menu"></i><span>Menu</span>
        </a>
        <?php include ("includes/menu.php"); ?>
    </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->
    
    <main class="bg_gray pattern">
        
        <div class="container margin_60_40">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="sign_up">
                        <div class="head">
                            <div class="title">
                            <h3><?php echo _e("Registration") ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /head -->
                        <div class="main">
                        <form action="includes/register.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
                        <h6><?php echo _e("Personal details") ?></h6>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("First and Last Name");?>" id="full_name" name="full_name" required>
                                <i class="icon_pencil"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Apartment (Optional)");?>" id="apartment" name="apartment">
                                <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Adress");?>" id="adress" name="adress" required>
                                <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("City");?>" id="city" name="city" required>
                                <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Postal Code");?>" id="postalcode" name="postalcode" maxlength="6" minlength="6" required>
                                <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Phone (888-888-8888)");?>" id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" maxlength="10" minlength="10" required>
                                <i class="icon_phone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Email Address");?>" id="email" name="email" required>
                                <i class="icon_mail"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group add_bottom_15">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _e("Password (8 character minimum)");?>" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" required>
                                <i class="icon_lock"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="refer" id="refer" value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['pid'])){echo $_SESSION['pid'];}else{}?>">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn_1 full-width mb_5" name="submit" value="<?php echo _e("Sign up Now");?>">
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /box_booking -->
                </div>
                <!-- /col -->

            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
        
    </main>
    <!-- /main -->

    <?php include ("includes/footer.php"); ?>

    <div id="toTop"></div><!-- Back to top button -->
    
    <div class="layer"></div><!-- Opacity Mask Menu Mobile -->
    
    <?php include("includes/signin-modal.php"); ?>
    
    <!-- COMMON SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/common_scripts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common_func.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/validate.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working exept when i try to pay with my Sandbox Personal or Business account, i am getting an error...

Here is the error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException:
> {"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","details":[{"location":"path","issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified
> resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try
> again."}],"message":"The specified resource does not
> exist.","debug_id":"17a56f649394f","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]} in
> /home/superrab/public_html/beta/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php:215
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/superrab/public_html/beta/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(100):
> PayPalHttp\HttpClient->parseResponse(Object(PayPalHttp\Curl)) #1
> /home/superrab/public_html/beta/transaction-completed.php(24):
> PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest))
> #2 /home/superrab/public_html/beta/transaction-completed.php(65): Sample\GetOrder::getOrder('7KM15574UC31371...', true) #3 {main} thrown
> in
> /home/superrab/public_html/beta/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php
> on line 215

Any help is appreciated

Comment: i been on this for 4 hours now i am starting to get crazy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2023 Update: actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and neither should be used for any new integration. See the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) which has an example of creating and capturing an order on a server when a payer clicks a JS SDK button.

---

I see this is a client-side only integration for payment creation and capture, where then after that client-side capture you use a server=side AI call to get the details of the order.  That's a very strange hybrid, one wonders why you didn't integrate 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction [on the server side](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/) (and paired with the [approval JS for a server side integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)) to get all the benefits of that robustness, and then you wouldn't need an additional API call to get the details of the order since you would already have it after the server-side capture and be able to store it atomically. Basically, it seems you really should switch to that instead of this unnecessary hybrid you're trying to do.

---

But if you insist on doing weird and inadvisable things that nobody recommends, Order IDs like 7KM15574UC313712P weren't created by your server-side code, and so can't be accessed that way.  What you can try instead is to look up the successful Capture ID (not Order ID) in the JS, from `purchase_units[0].captures.id` , and pass this actual PayPal transaction ID to your server code instead.  Then use it to get the v2/payment capture object, which will use a different API/SDK call -- in your case, this one: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK/blob/develop/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Payments/CapturesGetRequest.php

(But again, ideally this whole paragraph would be moot and you would pay more attention to paragraph #1)

Comment: Brother i followed a youtube video i dont insist on doing weird things lmao ... and why you corrected my text ?

Comment: So you saying i should use this instead : https://jsfiddle.net/aonrkzxs/ 
I have the file created because i tried it with this one too but dont work so .......

Comment: If you implement a Capture Order, you'll also need a Create Order ('Set Up Transaction' in the documentation). These will be 2 routes that your JavaScript code can call, per the server-side demo

Comment: And i dont understand javascript really well sorry for that.

Comment: If you use the server-side demo, the JavaScript is basically all written for you already --  you just need 2 server routes that operate on and return the right data

Comment: But i will look at this tomorrow it's 1:20 am here. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I cant setup something i dont understand lmao .... O.o